# Is there a way to switch from api.ai to action sdk

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have a action on google project that has api.ai enabled. Is there a way to switch from api.ai to action sdk?

[image]

Comment: Please See this first: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
[What-topics-can-I-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @ankit suthar Thanks for your suggestion. Can you please be a bit more specific? What is the problem of my question?

Comment: This seems like a perfectly appropriate question to me. It involves a software development tool that is required for actions-on-google.

Comment: This question is appropriate.
I also wanted to switch from api.ai to actions-sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just start using the gactions tool to use the Actions SDK. You can use the same project as you did for API.AI.

Both API.AI and the gactions tool call the same API to create an action package and set the app into test mode.